# Replace or ignore sub-imported files

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I want to import `fileA`

Inside `fileA` I import `fileB`:

```
import fileB
```

However, there is a syntax error in `fileB`! This causes importing `fileA` to fail.

I'm trying to ignore or remove the imports in fileA - the trick is that I need to import fileA via filepath, and so I have the following:

```
import importlib.util
def import_file_via_path(path, moduleName):

    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(moduleName, path)
    imported_module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(imported_module)

    return imported_module
```

How could I interrupt fileA's subimports or replace them before the original imports are executed? I can’t catch the import error in fileA, I have to find away to ignore/replace from where fileA is being imported via ‘importlib’.

Comment: Would a `try: import fileA ... except: import fileA without fileB` work? Or maybe you're asking how to do the import A without B part... which I don't exactly know how to...

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot catch it within fileA, I need to ignore /replace the import fileB from where fileA is being imported.

Comment: You could create your own dummy `fileB.py` in a different directory and add `sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/dummydir')`. Now the importer will find it first. ..... and then `fileA` will crash when it tries to use it.

Comment: I don't want `fileA` to crash, I want it to import successfully without the imports from `fileB`. Would their be away to do this without editing sys.path?